# Python Permutation Optimization

Tags: python, optimization

I was working with permutations in python for a project of mine, unlike most existing permutation functions, instead of getting every single possible solution, I was wanting to get one attached to a specific index...

```
l = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

I did this by basically making a list called "indices", and then overflowing values from the last value up through the list regressively (based on the length of any lists in the larger list, which is appended to the list called "lengths")... This works, however, I was wondering if there were any ways to optimize this script, as it seems very clunky to me so far...

I was working with Python and I was wondering if there was a way to optimize the following code...

```
    def Permutation(slots, index):
        # Declare Variables
        lengths = []
        indices = []
        for slot in range(0, len(slots)):
            lengths.append(len(slots[slot]))
            if slot == (len(slots) - 1):
                indices.append(index)
            else:
                indices.append(0)
        
        # Overflow up the list
        for slot in range(len(slots)-1, 0, -1):
            add_to = int(indices[slot] / lengths[slot])
            indices[slot] %= lengths[slot]

            indices[slot - 1] += add_to

        out = []
        it = 0
        for index in indices:
            out.append(slots[it][index])
            it += 1
        
        print(out)
```

Above is the main function, and below are examples of inputs and outputs:

```
Permutation(l, 26)
```

> [2, 2, 2]

```
Permutation(l, 27)
```

> IndexError: list index out of range

```
Permutation(l, 17)
```

> [1, 2, 2]

```
Permutation(l, 4)
```

> [0, 1, 1]

I know there are existing libraries, however, I was wanting to implement permutations in this specific way...

Comment: I've read this 3 times and I'm still confused.  First point:  *never* use the letter **l** for a variable name, it is too confusing with the number 1.  Can you add some detail about what the "list" refers to, and what the end goal is, perhaps with an end-to-end example.  Hopefully that will clear up whatever `index` revers to as well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AirSquid I got the answer farther down the page... Sorry for the confusion. And thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not permutations but product at a given index.  You can interpret your index as a number expressed in a varying base corresponding to the length of each sublist.  Convert each "digit" in that base to an index in the corresponding list using divmod as you would do to decompose a number in a fixed base bu changing the denominator at each iteration:

```
def prodAtIndex(L,i):
    result = []                     # product fed in reversed order           
    for v in reversed(L):           # from least significant to most
        i,p = divmod(i,len(v))      # get digit in current 'base'
        result.insert(0,v[p])       # build product
    return result if i==0 else None # i will end at zero if in range
```

output:

```
l = [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]

print(prodAtIndex(l, 26)) # [2, 2, 2]
print(prodAtIndex(l, 27)) # None
print(prodAtIndex(l, 17)) # [1, 2, 2]
print(prodAtIndex(l, 4))  # [0, 1, 1]
```